# Enable blinking of JLabel 3 times and then remain invisible/disappear

Tags: java, swing, timer, jlabel

I intend on writing java code which controls a JLabel to blink three times and then after the third blink enable the text within it to remain transparent/"disappear."

As indicated from the code below, I've been able to write a JLabel which continuously blinks but would like to create one that blinks only three times and then enable the text within it to remain transparent.

```
public class BlinkLabel extends JLabel {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      private static final int BLINKING_RATE = 1000; // in ms

      private boolean blinkingOn = true;

      public Timer timer;

      public BlinkLabel(String text) {
        super(text);            
        timer = new Timer( BLINKING_RATE , new TimerListenerTwo());
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();

      }

      public void setBlinking(boolean flag) {
        this.blinkingOn = flag;
      }

      public boolean getBlinking(boolean flag) {
        return this.blinkingOn;
      }

      public class TimerListenerTwo implements ActionListener{
            int counter = 1;

            public TimerListenerTwo() {

            }

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                if(counter == 3){//3 = YOUR MAX
                    timer.stop();
                }
                counter++;
            }
       }
}
```

I call the above function as follows:

```
BlinkLabel label = new BlinkLabel("");
label.setText("Blink blink");
```

How can I edit my above code to enable the JLabel to blink three time and have the text disappear.

Any ideas/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, btw everything described in your question will be done in `new TimerListener(this)` only ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its very simple, create a sub class below in your JFrame or JDialog.

```
class LbBlink implements ActionListener {  
        private javax.swing.JLabel label;
        private java.awt.Color cor1 = java.awt.Color.red;
        private java.awt.Color cor2 = java.awt.Color.gray;
        private int count;

        public LbBlink(javax.swing.JLabel label){
            this.label = label;
        }
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(count % 2 == 0)
                label.setForeground(cor1);
            else
                label.setForeground(cor2);
            count++;
        }  
    }
```

Declare a variable in your class.

```
private Timer timerLB;
```

After, in your class construct set the variable.

```
timerLB = new Timer(1000, new "Your Class".LbBlink("Your jLabel"));
```

Finally, in your application, for start blink

```
timerLB.start();
```

And for stop:

```
timerLB.stop();
```

Answer (score 3):

try using a `counter` and increase the `counter` on every `blink` and if the counter is 3 then
clear the label's text `setText("")`

**EDIT**

```
class TimerListener implements ActionListener{
    int counter = 1;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        if(counter == 3){//3 = YOUR MAX
            timer.stop();
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the reply. Do you essentially mean I build a counter using a for loop as I've indicated in my edited code above such and once the counter gets to three set the text to setText("");

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the reply. I've edited my code above with the counter within a TimerListener class and utilised the TimerListener class as when creating the Timer object. After doing this I'm still unable to produce the blinking effect.

Answer (score 2):

- methods talking about usage of [Swing Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) instead of `ActionListener`, [Swing Action has implemented isEnabled()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html#isEnabled%28%29)

meaning code lines

```
  public void setBlinking(boolean flag) {
    this.blinkingOn = flag;
  }

  public boolean getBlinking(boolean flag) {
    return this.blinkingOn;
  }
```

- every changes to the (already visible) Swing GUI will be done inside `Swing Action`, `ActionListener` in your case
- there (maybe) not reason to subclassing JLabel, create an local variable for `JLabel`, `Swing Timer`,
- I miss there code `Timer.setRepeats(boolean)`

Answer (score 1):

Count blinks and when it is enough call [stop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#stop%28%29) on your timer.

Answer (score 0):

No timer is need.Simply using THREAD we can done it.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

class Sample {
   int i;
   private JFrame f;
   private JLabel l;

Sample() throws InterruptedException {
    f = new JFrame("test");
    f.setSize(400, 400);
    l = new JLabel("Testing");
    f.add(l);
    f.setVisible(true);

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            l.setForeground(Color.red);
        } else {
            l.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        }
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    l.setEnabled(false);

}

public static void main(String a[]) throws InterruptedException {
    new Sample();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested using displayHelpMessage (Reference: 
https://blog.ajduke.in/2014/03/31/java-how-to-schedule-a-task-to-run-in-an-interval/)

So, I used it and developed Java code that blinks given text 3 times on a JLabel(messageLabel) below. Hope this will help somebody out there.

```
    static int counter = 0;
    static ScheduledExecutorService service;

    void displayHelpMessage(String message) 
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // task to run goes here
                if (counter++ >= 6) {
                    service.shutdown();
                    counter = 0;
                } else {
                    if (counter % 2 == 1) {
                        messageLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                    } else {
                        messageLabel.setForeground(Color.black);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        messageLabel.setText(message);
        service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 750, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }   

// Call examples:       
    displayHelpMessage("How to select panel");        
    displayHelpMessage("Key to use complete create/modify");
```