# Java GUI, display a blinking string

Tags: java, string, swing, awt

Is there a method in Java to make a string appear in GUI while blinking?
I am writing a program and I need the string below to display while blinking. Thanks.

```
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 30));
        g.drawString("Game Over!!! Score: " + score, 190, 300);
```

Comment: You can use the code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524080/enable-blinking-of-jlabel-3-times-and-then-remain-invisible-disappear

Comment: Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43084698/flashing-label-in-javafx-gui) which is very similar

Comment: @csmckelvey *"You can use the code from.."* Indeed! In this case, change the actions from updating the label, to calling `repaint()`. I'd suggest after incrementing a counter, change the `Color` of a variable referenced in the paint method.